# How to align text vertically?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

What is the easiest way to align the text vertically [here](http://jsfiddle.net/na7F8/) with CSS ?

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Bye Bye</li>
    <li>Ciao</li>
</ul>

li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have just one line of text, you can set the `line-height` to the same value as the `height`. This works for any element.

Answer (score 1):

Hacky, but possibly the easiest way:

```
li {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

You will need to add a background image in place of the list item bullet.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're always going to center a **single line** you could match `height` and `line-height`

```
li {
    ...
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the vertical-align property:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: Vertical align usually doesnt work in the way you'd think.
http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Putting a line-height and making a gap between text and the border is good. but this is not the best practice. because Line height is not for creating a margin or padding. It is for creating a gap between two text lines(gap between two lines of a paragraph).

So make your task is done, you have to put a margin or a padding. The better option is putting a margin( But this is not a alignment. Just putting a margin to top ). And also, put your text into a "p" tag or "span" tag( whatever a tag, which can use for wrap text ).

HTML code,

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Hello</span></li>
    <li><span>Bye Bye</span></li>
    <li><span>Ciao</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS Code,

```
ul li span {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

If making verticaly align is must, Here is the code.

```
  ul li {
     position: relative;
  }

  ul li span {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      font-size: 12px; /* change this as your need. */
      line-height: 12px; /* keep this value same as font-size. */
      margin-top: -6px; /* half value from the font-size. */

}
```