# Cant vertically align text!

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know its extremely simple, but I have been coding all day and it doesn't seem to work.

I want the text to be vertically centered inside the box.. What am i doing doing?

http://jsfiddle.net/UAyNh/

**UPDATE:
That worked for the text, but the buttons wont center. Check it out on Safari vs. Chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/Bz9pB/**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826681/how-to-align-text-vertically)

Comment: This has been asked so many times!

Comment: @redsquare -- yes, proving again that the css spec has negative value as a practical guide for the everyday user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give a container **line-height** equal to its height.

eg.

```
div.box
{
     line-height: 40px;
     height: 40px;
}
```

The only other way I know is to either use a table or replicate a table with CSS:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And

```
div.table{ display: table; }
div.row{ display: table-row; }

div.cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: His demo with the same fix: http://jsfiddle.net/UAyNh/2/ - you should note that this technique only works for a single line of text.

Answer (score 1):

Use `line-height` and make that equal to the `height` of the element (so long as your element only has one line, anyway):

```
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UAyNh/1/).

Comment: @JD Audi, I'm on Ubuntu 11.04, so Safari's not an option for me to check with. It seems to work on both Chromium 11 and Firefox 4, though.

Answer (score 0):

If the text will be on one line and the height of that line is similar to that in your example, you can solve it by setting the line-height:

```
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
```

Comment: The technique does work, but the buttons occupy too much space and don't fit on the same line as the text, at least not in the last demo.

Comment: cant I center the buttons in the box as well?

Comment: That should work if there is enough room for the buttons to appear next to the text. In your example the buttons and the text do not fit on the same line, so you should reduce the text and/or reduce the button size and/or make the available space larger. The latter may not be possible on jsfiddle.net.