# Problem vertically aligning text of an element that spans two lines

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I want to align some text in the middle of my element using CSS. This is my markup:

```
<div id="testimonial">
    <span class="quote">Some random text that spans two lines</span>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```css
#testimonial {
    background: url('images/testimonial.png') no-repeat;
    width: 898px;
    height: 138px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}

.quote {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Verdanna, Arial, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #676767;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #e7e7e7;
}
```

Usually to get `.quote` in the vertical middle of `#testimonial`, I'd do:

```css
.quote { line-height: 138px; }
```

But this breaks the layout because the text in `.quote` spans more than one line.

As you can see I've tried doing `vertical-align: middle;` and that doesn't work either.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826681/how-to-align-text-vertically)

Comment: No, `line-height` doesn't work in this case because my text is more than one line.

Comment: @minitech: That's not a good duplicate. The accepted answer is using `line-height`, which is no good for multiple lines. The `display: table-cell` answer is there, but it has no explanation and no upvotes.

Comment: The "easiest" way is to use/mimic a table (either in markup or in CSS using table-cell) and then set to display valign="middle". But it's dirty. Oh so dirty.

Comment: @thirtydot: You're right - but there are lots to choose from. Let me find another.

Comment: A decent example: http://www.emblematiq.com/blog/vertical_align_with_css/ See the multiple line middle example.

Comment: `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` works, if you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Josh: Are you talking to me? I'll add it as answer if you like (who doesn't like free rep?), but note that it doesn't work in in IE7: http://caniuse.com/#search=table

Comment: @Josh Is this question still unanswered?

Answer (score 16):

I [recently found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084305/position-badge-over-corner-of-image-automatically/6086386#6086386) that vertical centering of something which has undefined dimensions goes very well with `vertical-align: middle;` in combination with `line-height: 0;`.

Check out this [demonstration fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/smytD/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="testimonial">
    <span><span class="quote">Some random text<br />that spans two lines</span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#testimonial {
    background: #333 url('images/testimonial.png') no-repeat;
    width: 898px;
    height: 138px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
    line-height: 138px;
}
#testimonial>span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.quote {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Verdanna, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #676767;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #e7e7e7;
    line-height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: In case you could not make it work in IE, try to use simple html5 doctype, like <!DOCTYPE html>. I found that it's not working in IE by using ugly XTHML doctype.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it simpler with single span
http://jsfiddle.net/7ebLd/

```
#testimonial {
    height: 138px;
    line-height: 138px;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 19px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as nobody's answered it with the table cell solution yet..

here you go - with an an IE6/7 solution too (though it involves a yukky HTML hack) as @thirtydot says in comments, table display properties are not supported by IE7 and below -

if you don't want/like the extra HTML element, you could just give IE7 and below some top padding on the `.quote` - so that while it wouldn't be vertically centered accurately it may be an acceptable fall back

**CSS:**

```css
#testimonial {
    background: #eee url('images/testimonial.png') no-repeat;
    width: 898px;
    height: 138px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    padding: 0 30px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.quote {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #676767;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #e7e7e7;
}
```

**IE CSS:**

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#testimonial i {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.quote {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="testimonial">
    <i></i>
    <span class="quote">Some random text <br> that spans two lines</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This website offers a plethora of [options for vertical centering with css](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

If you can set a height on `.quote`, I think Method 2 would work in this situation:

```css
.quote {
     position:absolute;
     top:50%;
     height:240px;
     margin-top:-120px; /* negative half of the height */
}
```

Another option is to use `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` method in CSS, but this option does not work in IE, so you'll have to also set an IE-specific version.

Answer (score 0):

This site:

http://www.emblematiq.com/blog/vertical_align_with_css/

With the result:

http://www.emblematiq.com/blog/vertical_align_with_css/assets/03.html

Uses the following markup/css to center vertically multiple lines using the `display: table-cell`, `vertically-align: middle` method:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="0.gif" alt="stuff" id="fixed" />
    <div id="floating"><div><div>
<p>Middle aligned text goes right here and it does wrap nicely at the end of the line</p>
    </div></div></div>
</div>
```

```css
p {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
    width:550px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    padding:10px;
    height:300px;
}
#fixed {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:#666;
    display:block;
}
#wrapper>#floating { /*display:table for Mozilla & Opera*/
    display:table;
    position:static;
}
#floating { /*for IE*/
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    background:#EAEAEA;
    position:relative;
}
#floating div { /*for IE*/
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
}
#floating>div { /*for Mozilla and Opera*/
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:static;
}
#floating div div {
    position:relative;
    top:-50%;
}
```

[image: Result]