# CSS Vertically Align Text in Header

Tags: css, text, alignment

I am trying to vertically align text in my header, and am having some trouble.  Attached is an image of my starting point:

[image: Preview]

The header has a set height of 141px and everything in that header should be right in the middle.  Even the *"Name of Website Here"*, so if that name changes and only takes up 1 line, or maybe 3 lines it will all be in the same place.

**Note:** this is for multiple websites, which are being generated dynamically so that's why I cannot just position it with a `margin-top` because the names will be different, some might take up a few lines and some might take up multiple lines.

---

I took out my attempts to vertically align it from what I searched online because nothing is working so this is the code from my starting point.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Name of Website Here</h1>
    <h3>Call Today!<br /><span>(xxx) xxx-xxxx</span></h3>
    <p>123 Main St.<br />City, State, Zip</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header{height:141px;}
#header h1{float:left;font-size:1.7em;width:200px;text-align:center;line-height:26px}
#header h3{float:left;text-align:center;color:#e62520;font-size:1.7em;line-height:26px;font-style:italic;margin:0 0 0 95px}
#header h3 span{font-size:1.2em;}
#header p{float:right;color:#2a5091;font-size:1.3em;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;line-height:20px;text-align:right;}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Were going to have to see some HTML/CSS to get the best answer, without seeing code I would say the width is wrong.

Comment: What browsers are you trying to support? Because you could probably use `display:inline-block` or `display:table-cell` to make it work, but you'd likely have some IE6/7 issues.

Comment: Updated with my starting code!

Comment: [Do you need IE6 or 7 support?](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201007-201107)

Comment: I do for IE 7, I don't care about IE 6.

Comment: It's not the real design it is just the framework with basic CSS styles for now.  Thank you for your concern though.

Comment: @Drew I think my answer below should solve your problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, see [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/7Hz2R/1/).

The markup will become like:

```
<div id="header">
    <span><h1>Name of Website Here</h1></span>
    <span><h3>Call Today!<br /><span>(xxx) xxx-xxxx</span></h3></span>
    <div><span><p>123 Main St.<br />City, State, Zip</p></span></div>
</div>
```

Maybe you can fiddle around some more to eliminate one or two tags.

Tested on Win7 in IE8, IE9, Opera 11.50, Safari 5.0.5, FF 5.0, Chrome 12.0. I know [it is also possible to work in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180034/problem-vertically-aligning-text-of-an-element-that-spans-two-lines/6245662#6245662), but it needs some tuning. T.b.c.

Comment: Just gotta work on that IE 7 issue, it really messes up the whole layout now.

Comment: this doesn't work if you have more or less than two lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a great method. Create a div inside the header div and give it the following style :

```
.innerdiv {height:1px; position:absolute; margin-top:50% }
```

And make sure the header div has

```
position:relative;
```

And put all your content inside innerdiv

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't quite get that to work but I appreciate you trying.