# How to vertical align tag in a div

Tags: css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="news_item">    
    <div class="featured_leftpart">
        <img src="" width="48" height="48" />
    </div>
    <div class="featured_rightpart">
        <div class="news_content">
            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="" >TEXT </a></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and using this CSS:

```
.news_item
{
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    height:100px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

div.featured_leftpart
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:64px;
    height:100%;
}

div.featured_leftpart img{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#ff00ff;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}

div.featured_rightpart
{
    background-color:#ff0000;    
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:100%;
}

.news_content
{
    background-color:#00ff00;
    position:relative;
}

.news_content h2
{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to vertical align h2 tag. This tag will contain a post title, so sometimes it will be single line, sometimes multiline. 
Also that `<div class="news_content">` is just my attempt to make it work. If there is a solution without this `div`, I can easily remove it.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/httpb/cJaSL/) link to the code above.

Comment: Are you trying to align the top of the text to `.featured_leftpart img` ?

Comment: I want the h2 to be in the vertical middle of the ".featured_rightpart div "the same way img tag is in the middle of ".featured_leftpart div"

Comment: I also tried for h2 to be display:inline and that also didn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cJaSL/17/ Like this?

Comment: the problem in this question looks pretty similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084100/css-vertically-align-text-in-header

Comment: Yes, just like that. Create an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Thanks DrCopyPaste. Looks interesting. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending from comment:

No need to add an extra `.news_content`, just tell browser how high is a line and `vertical-align` will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/cJaSL/17/

```
<div class="featured_rightpart">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="" >TEXT </a></h2>
</div>
```

```css
div.featured_rightpart
{
    line-height:100px; /* calculated from .news_item */
}
.featured_rightpart h2
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-top:0px; /* need this to clear the default margin */
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

Beware, though, that this solution only works if there's only one line in title.

**Edit**:

In case multiline is not avoidable, the wrapper seems not avoidable too:

http://jsfiddle.net/cJaSL/18/

```
<div class="featured_rightpart">
    <div class="title_wrapper">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="" >TEXT<br />multi<br />line </a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
div.title_wrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1.25em; /* can adjust to look nice */
}
```

Comment: And I'm wondering why it doesn't work on my development site. It's because every title is multilined:)

Comment: @user850010 Updated with a multiline solution :)

Comment: This doesn't stretch beyond 3 lines though, nor does it shrink when there's only one. Is there any way you can make the height scale?

Comment: @Trickery `.news_item` is set to be fixed in `100px` height, that's what OP defines, so I think it should not "shrink" or "stretch".

Comment: @Passerby Yeah, I just assumed he did this in an attempt to make it center vertically. Your solution is more elegant than mine.